# PDO FETCH_CLASS multiple rows into array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, oop, pdo

I'm trying to fetch multiple rows of bookings from a database and I want each one to be an instance of a specific class - so I attempted to store them within a multidimensional array.

So far it works in terms of creating the array of objects, however I need the index for the array to be the booking ID so that I can easily access each one. For example:

```
$bookings[id] => booking Object ( [name:protected] => name, [time:protected] => time )
```

Is this possible and is it the best way to go about what I want to achieve? Any help would be hugely appreciated, here's the code:

```
class create_bookings {


    private $db;
  protected $error;




function __construct($db, $current, $end) {

    $this->db = $db;


    $query = "SELECT id, name, time             
              FROM bookings";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query); 

    $stmt->execute(); 

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'booking');   

    print_r($result);

}

}
```

...and the 'booking' class is just a set of properties:

```
class booking {

      private $db;

    protected $name;
    protected $time;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of building a class to create the booking objects, it would be advisable to either create a standalone function, or a function within a parent class to achieve this.  The issue I run in to with using `fetchAll()` with the `FETCH_CLASS` parameter, is that the objects do not automatically have access to the database object, causing you to need to iterate over the objects afterwards anyways, so I simply build the `__construct()` method to capture the `$db` and generated array.

Assuming you go the route of a standalone function:

```
function create_bookings($db, $current, $end) {
    $query = "SELECT id, name, time             
              FROM bookings";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 

    $stmt->execute(); 

    $result = array()

    $bookings = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if($bookings) {
        foreach($bookings as $booking) {
            $result[$booking['id']] = new booking($db, $booking);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


class booking {

    private $db;
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $time;

    public function __construct($db, $array) {
        if(/*validate your array here*/) {
            $this->db = $db;
            $this->id = $array['id'];
            $this->name = $array['name'];
            $this->time = $array['time'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant thanks, that's really helped me to understand it. your approach makes far more sense than what I was trying to achieve. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to do this.

The trick is `PDO::FETCH_GROUP`. Just do

```
   $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'booking');
```

The only downside to this is that there will be an array in every result before the Object

There's a simple way to remove the array too

```
$output= array_map('reset',$result);
```

Comment: That's great thanks. I see what you mean about the array, must be a way to remove that. Is there a better way to go about this overall than to put the objects in an array?

Comment: The above method should give you your objects directly in the array